# Changing The Property Of An Object Using Variables? C#/Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, object, button, iteration

Ok so I have 100 buttons and I need to change there colors based on conditions in a while loop. They are named button1, button2, button3 ,etc. during the first time around the loop (iteration?) I need to edit button1, the next time button2 the third time button3, etc.

I thought I could just make a string that equaled "button", add the number of times around the loop to it and change the color like that.

`String ButtonNumber = "button" + i;` where i = number of times around loop

When I try to edit the color using `ButtonNumber.BackColor = Color.Red;` it won't let me because it's not treating ButtonNumber like a button, but like a string. How do I accomplish this? Thanks! (this is my first time programing pretty much)

Comment: Put your buttons into an array then iterate over the array.

Comment: Also, is this WinForms, WPF, Silverlight, WebForms, or something else?

Comment: This is A WindowsForumsApplication1. If possible could you show me an example. I don't know what an array is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using `Controls.Find` to find a control by name, and then you can change it's properties:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
{
    var buttonName = string.Format("button{0}", i);

    var foundControl = Controls.Find(buttonName, true).FirstOrDefault();

    if (foundControl != null)
    {
        // You can now set any common control property using the found control
        foundControl.BackColor = Color.Red;

        // If you need to set button-specific properties (i.e. properties
        // that are not common to all controls), then cast it to a button:
        var buttonControl = foundControl as Button;

        if (buttonControl != null)
        {
            buttonControl.AutoEllipsis = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! I tired that, but the "button{0}" is underlined in red. The error says "Too many characters in character literal"  Any ideas?

Comment: FYI for the OP. You'll need cast it to a button if you need Button specific properties and methods -- `Button actualButton = (Button) buttonControl;`

Comment: where should I put the cast thing, and is it supposed to fix the error?

Comment: Backcolor is common to all controls, so you won't need to cast for that. But if you do need to set a button-specific property, such as `AutoEllipsis`, I included an example of casting in the sample above...

Comment: Thank you, but does anybody know how to fix the "Too many Charters in charter literal" error?

Comment: You are probably missing a quote somewhere - copy paste error?

Comment: Sounds like you might be using single quotes somewhere.  Check to see if all your string literals have double quotes.  Single quotes denote a character literal 'a' and double quotes denote a string literal "Matt is awesome"

Comment: A sidenote, it sounds like you could use a learning book/tool.  You could try pluralsight or maybe some of the head first books to learn the basics

Comment: Thank you! It worked I had used ' not ". I will look into those books!